# Get whole XML tags from XMLfile using XSLT

Tags: xml, xslt

How can a get a full XML tag including its opening and closing brackets `<>` using XSLT, like the xml below I would like to out put in a string the whole file, is this possible?

```
<parent><child>Tom</child></parent>
```

I want the output in a html page or a javascript string to be like this

```
<parent><child>Tom</child></parent>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You haven't shown any of your current XSLT but I suspect you're using `xsl:value-of` where you should be using `xsl:copy-of`.

Given an XML file like

```
<root>
  <parent><child>Tom</child></parent>
</root>
```

The instruction

```
<xsl:value-of select="/root/parent"/>
```

will create a single text node with value "Tom", whereas

```
<xsl:copy-of select="/root/parent"/>
```

will copy the whole `parent` element to the result tree.

Comment: will this output the whole file <> brackets included??  I've tried in a html page with a textarea tag and a data tag but just whats between the brackets shows..

Comment: @M_K It's hard to visualise exactly what you're asking for, can you edit your question to include a sample of the the real input XML, what you need as output, and the XSLT you've tried so far?  You need to stop thinking in terms of "text with angle brackets" - XSLT operates on the XML tree structure of elements, attributes and text nodes so it doesn't "output the angle brackets", it creates element nodes in the output tree.

Comment: I need to pass on the xml String so I can do some processing on that text in JavaScript..for example II want to do processing on the element <parent><child>Tom</child></parent> the whole lot not just Tom, does that make it clearer?